# A $L^p$ function, which is not in other $L^q$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

A function defined on $[0,\infty)$ is said to be in $L^p$ if $\int_0^\infty |f|^p dx<\infty$. How can we find a function which is in $L^p$, but not in other $L^q$, $q\neq p$. Here, $0<p,q<\infty$.

Something like $x^{-a}$ is not sufficient...

Comment: I know someones but they construction are difficult/tedious. First find an $L^p$ function that cannot belong to any $L^q$ for $q<p$. Then find another $L^p$ function but this time ensure that it cannot belong to any $L^q$ space for $q>p$. Then you can get an idea of how to construct a function that only belong to $L^p$ from the two previous functions (by example dividing $[0,\infty)$ in two disjoint subsets of infinite measure and pluging each previous function on one of these subsets).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\left (\frac{1}{x(\ln x)^2}(\chi_{(0,1/2)} + \chi_{(2,\infty)})\right)^{1/p}
$$

Comment: Can you explain why this function satisfies the answer please? It's no problem if you don't want to, but it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @jsmith On the interval $(0,1/2),$ this function equals $1/[x(\ln x)^2]^{1/p}. $If you raise this to the $pth$ power, you get $1/[x(\ln x)^2]\in L^1(0,1/2).$ What happens if you raise it to the $q$th power, $q> p?$